# HTTP Requests through Python socket library

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to issue a simple HTTP GET request to a website through Python socket library. The sample website I used here is https://azlyrics.com/lyrics/charlieputh/attention.html. My code is:

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'azlyrics.com';
serverPort = 80;
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);
print(clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort)));
message = '''GET /lyrics/charlieputh/attention.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.azlyrics.com
Connection: keep-alive
''';
print(message);
clientSocket.send(message.encode());
modifiedMessage = clientSocket.recv(2048).decode();
print(modifiedMessage);
clientSocket.close();
```

But I get no response message in return. Also the object I get in return of `connect()` is None. I have tried the same URL with Python Request Library and it works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests body should end with `\r\n` (CR-LF),

please try this:

```py
from socket import *
serverName = 'azlyrics.com';
serverPort = 80;
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);
print(clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort)));
message = '''GET /lyrics/charlieputh/attention.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.azlyrics.com
Connection: keep-alive


''';
print(message);
clientSocket.send(message.encode());
modifiedMessage = clientSocket.recv(2048).decode();
print(modifiedMessage);
clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: I dont know WTF is wrong with me? How did I missed that simple thing... Anyway thanks a lot you saved me a week of headache

Comment: Is there any resource over internet where I can read issuing HTTPS requests?

Comment: you can try using Python`s `ssl`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html . so that it takes for the S part for you.